# How does OS scheduler return?

Tags: timer, process, kernel, interrupt, scheduler

I am developing a simple kernel for my upcoming OS. I have developed everything till the scheduler. I am wondering how the scheduler comes into its cycle.

For example,

1. The TIMER interrupt fires.
2. The handler calls the scheduler.
3. The scheduler jumps the next process in the queue.
4. The interrupt must return (IRETD)

But if the scheduler has to jump to the next process then when does the interrupt return. And if it does, wouldn't it go back to last process.

I want this clarification - How does the timer interrupt return to from scheduler and how does the scheduler communicate with timer interrupt (if with function call, then when does it return) ?

Assume - Monolithic Kernel

Comment: I'm not familiar with the peculiarities of the IRETD instructions, but I suppose it needs to pop the instruction pointer and other registers from some stack in order to resume.
The way I see it, you need to change the values in that stack, so that when IRETD pops what it needs, it effectively resumes the new process, instead of the one that was interrupted.
I can't give you specifics without studying that part of the x86 instruction set myself.
My experience comes mostly from my hobby project (https://bitbucket.org/ruifig/g4devkit), which is loosely based on ARM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a interrupt occurs, the processor switches its context. It does so by updating a flag in the EFLAGS register and pushing some information on the stack (can be seen in intel manuals). If the interrupt occurs in user-mode, then a stack-switch also occurs according to the TSS of the current task.

The scheduler process is done as -

1. Came from user-process with interrupt state pushed on stack
2. Pick next process
3. IRETD on interrupt state of new process